# Oracle unable to connect

Tags: oracle, macos, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, datagrip

I had a working SQLDeveloper/DataGrip installation. Cleaning up my hard drive I deleted and emptied the trash of my downloads folder. On attempting to connect to a database instance I receive:

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: /Users/rona/lib/instantclient_12_2/libocijdbc12.dylib: dlopen(/Users/rona/lib/instantclient_12_2/libocijdbc12.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/libclntsh.dylib.12.1
  Referenced from: /Users/rona/lib/instantclient_12_2/libocijdbc12.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

This file path does exist : `/Users/rona/lib/instantclient_12_2/libocijdbc12.dylib`

I think it's something related to `rpath` ?

Comment: set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to include this directory. Depending on which version of macos you're using, you may need to change your .sh to set this in there.

Comment: @gsalem thanks, Ive set this variable also but same error. I'm using Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: might be quicker to create a new connection type that won't try to load the oracle thick driver - are you using tnsnames and connect identifier? if so, switch to network alias